# Get Status of Bluetooth paired Epson printer

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, bluetooth, epson

#### The problem

I am currently working on an application which needs to send information to print on an **EPSON TM-U295** printer. Said printer has **Bluetooth** enabled and is paired with the computer. I am currently able to send a string to it and print the needed information. However, if there is no paper in the printer the string is still sent and printed on thin air.

#### Current code to print

Take note that `Socket` is a `StreamSocket` using the method `ConnectAsync()` which allows you to connect to a paired printer.

```
'Print
Public Async Function Write(ByVal StrToSend As String) As Task
    Dim Bytestosend As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StrToSend)
    Await Socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(Bytestosend.AsBuffer())
    Await Socket.OutputStream.FlushAsync()
End Function

'Send the command to print
Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Await Write(txtTextTosend.Text + vbLf)
End Sub
```

#### Code wanted

I would like to be able to verify if the paper is out with a condition similar to the following :

```
'Send the command to print
Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    if Status <> PRINTER_PAPER_OUT then
        Await Write(txtTextTosend.Text + vbLf)
    End if
End Sub
```

#### R&D

I have noticed in the [Documentation](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/3/9uC-APD402_T81_Status.pdf) (Page 10-11 of another EPSON printer model) a certain `ASB Status` which is defined as follows:

Auto Status Back: This is a function of the **TM printer**. This is a status
automatically sent from the printer when the printer status changes
(opening or closing the cover, **out of paper**, print completed, etc.).

It is later mentioned (Page 22) that `ASB_RECEIPT_END` is a constant which is linked with the printer having no paper

[More documentation](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/36/Scx-APD_TM_StatusAPI_RefGuide.pdf)

#### The Question

How do we use the `ASB status` mentioned earlier to know if the printer is in a "Out of Paper" state ?

If the `ASB status` is not the way to go to obtain the information could someone point me in the correct direction ?

**Note that I do not mind C# or VB.NET code**

Comment: Please take note that being very new to this kind of interaction, (I am used to simple Form to Form or Form to SQL Server interactions) I am finding it very difficult to find information I understand through the documentation. Other SO post answers I have stumbled upon seem mostly irrelevant to solve this

Answer (score 0):

#### What needs to be done

- **Learn about and use ESC/POS commands**
- Activate the ASB (`GS a` command)
- Activate the Group Separator Command `GS`

  This will separate the `Write` for the `ASB` and the `Write` for the Text avoiding to print something like : `aTEXTTOPRINT`
- Read the status sent back from the printer
- Verify if the state is out of paper

#### The Code

- First a `READ` function is needed which will read the bytes and convert it to a string

  ```
  Dim bytes(2000) As Byte ' 2000 bytes is random I wasnt sure how many were needed 

  Dim result = Await Socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(bytes.AsBuffer, bytes.Length, InputStreamOptions.Partial)
  Dim lgtOfRead = result.Length
  Dim readstr As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
  Dim retstr As String = readstr.Take(lgtOfRead).ToArray()
  Return retstr
  ```
- Secondly it is needed to send the commands mentioned above for this to work

  ```
  'Send the command to print
  Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      Dim cmd As Byte() = {29, 97} 'Send the command to enable ASB
      Await _Btcomm.Write(cmd)

      cmd = {29} 'Separate the information
      Await _Btcomm.Write(cmd)

      Dim strResult As String = Await _Btcomm.Read()

      'Verify if the status has a "`" character linked to paper out state
      If Not strResult.Contains("`") Then
          Await _Btcomm.Write(txtTextTosend.Text + vbLf)
      Else
          Dim md As MessageDialog = New MessageDialog("The printer has no paper", "No Paper")
          Await md.ShowAsync()
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

#### Documentation

[Some commands](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72)

[Some more commands](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/epson_printer_codes.html)

[MOAR Commands](http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf)

http://www.asciitable.com  (ASCII table makes it easier to figure out commands)